# How to center a menu li without centering sub menu

Tags: html, css

I want to center a menu without centering sub-menu, this is my code:

```
<ul class="drop_menu">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">hhh</a>
    <ul class="sub_drop_menu">
         <li><a href="#">Home</a></li> 
         <li><a href="#">Home</a></li> 
         <li><a href="#">Home</a></li> 
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

this is the css that i'm using :

```
 .drop_menu {
    list-style-type:none;
    height:30px;
    }
    .drop_menu > li { 
      float:left; 
      font-weight: bold;  
      font-size: 16px;  
    }
    ul.drop_menu > li {
        text-align: center;  
    }
```

Comment: show us your tried code..

Comment: Not enough information.

Comment: @Tukhsanov my problem is that i use this css .drop_menu > li { 
  float:left;  
text-align: center; 
} but it center both the menu and sub-menu items , i want to center just the menu items

Comment: @gfullam my problem is that i use this css .drop_menu > li { float:left; text-align: center; } but it center both the menu and sub-menu items , i want to center just the menu items

Comment: Post your CSS - and make a jsFiddle.

Comment: Yeah it's not clear to me what you want exactly and since my answer doesn't really solve your problem (whatever it might be), I will delete it.

Comment: @Irdrah i don't what to say , my question was clear , i have a menu and sub_menu , i'm trying to center the text that is in the menu , but when i do that it center also the text of sub_menu , me i want to center just the menu menu menu menu not sub_menu , is it clear now.

Comment: "Center a menu" is not clear. Center the whole block - the text etc. People say it's not clear - so then - it is NOT clear, in which case - you compose a clearer question instead of getting snippy. You are asking for help. Try harder. Start with some decent code. http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/GwA73/  If you want to target the sub_menu --- then target the sub menu with a CSS rule. If you don't know how to write CSS, then maybe you should ask that question or google it.

Comment: @user3546035 nobody gets what you are trying to achieve hence the lack of answers to your question. I can't even begin to understand how you can say that your question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this css to your code hope it will work

```
.sub_drop_menu li {
    text-align: left;  
}
```

Comment: add above code after ul.drop_menu > li {
        text-align: center;  
    }

Comment: There is no need for the `ul.sub_drop_menu` unless you are calling something that is not a ul - sub_drop_menu somewhere else. It's unnecessarily over qualified and will cause problems with specificity later on.

Comment: yes you r right, without using ul it will align all content inside the class if any alignment is not applied after

Answer (score 1):

### HOW CSS WORKS

"Cascading" Style Sheets.

a "Rule" - a selector and then 1 or more "declarations" of property and value.

```
.your-selector {
    property: value;
}
```

Read it from right to left...

```
.menu li {
    text-align: center;
}
```

"Any (and all) li - within .menu --- text-align: center;

So this means your .sub-menu's li are going to be text align center, because it is an li within .menu.   --- you make the rules.

You can do one of two things in this situation.

```
.sub-menu li { /* this overrides the "cascading" rule from before */
    text-align: right;
}
```

or

```
.menu > li {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Which would mean, all li in the first tier --- the first children of .menu

Here is [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/GwA73/)